# Can electric (and magnetic) field lines be used as a curvilinear coordinate system?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, electrostatics, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Can electric field lines be used as a curvilinear coordinate system?

I think they can, since they never cross, although they are likely to form only one set of the coordinate curves (alternatively one could think of equipotential surfaces as coordinate surfaces).

What I am looking for is a clear mathematical statement that (or when) the solutions of the Poisson/Laplace equation give us a set of curves that satisfy the necessary requirements for being coordinate lines. (Thus, the question is likely addressed to the people with background in general relativity or elasticity)

Background: the question is motivated by [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/610992/247642).

As a bonus, I welcome a similar discussion about the magnetic field lines.

Answer (score 1):

As it happens I was working on a similar problem, trying to generalize the Taxicab metric which I used in an art project before (archive.bridgesmathart.org/2019/bridges2019-107.pdf). If I understand things correctly, I have a proposal which works for two-dimensional problems: take the field lines as one set of curves, and the equipotential lines as the other set. They are nicely orthogonal everywhere. Feyman has lectured on the Laplace equation in 2D, his image 7-1 (https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_07.html) shows perhaps an example of the coordinate lines you might be looking for. For 3D, I have no idea, unless the configuration happens to be something extruded.